# GWT handling key combination

Tags: events, gwt

I want to handle a combination of keys (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>) being pressed together.

I've tried to do this ...

```
if ((event.getCharCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER)
                && event.isControlKeyDown()) {
                //do smth...
}
```

...but it does not work. I've also tried to see the code of this combination and it shows 10. So I could probably do `event.getCharCode() == 10` but I think that is not very good practice, especially since there are such methods in the API as `isControlKeyDown()` and others. What is the appropriate method of catching key combinations?

Comment: Which event are you handling?  I find that when trying to catch enter keys it's best to handle the KeyPressEvent.

Comment: I'm trying to catch KeyPressEvent with KeyPressHandler

Comment: This is a nice page for testing JS key events: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html .  At the bottom you can test key events; you'll have to test with a few different browsers. Granted it's not GWT but I found it useful.

Comment: For what it's worth, `10 == \n`, but I'd recommend sticking to the constants, if not only for legibility, for potentially handling sticky edge cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite the comment I wrote to your question, it seems that the better event to handle is `KeyUpEvent`.  In that case you can get the correct `KeyCode` and test for the modifier.  The same situation applies for `KeyDownEvent`, however, as the user holds the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key down, you will get multiple `KeyDownEvents` waiting for them to press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, while there should only be a single `KeyUpEvent`.

Also this solution seems more cross-browser compatible than testing for `charCode() == 10` in `KeyPressEvent`.  Firefox doesn't seem to set the charCode to 10 for <kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Here is some code I used to test in Chrome, IE8, and FF8:

```
package com.test.gwt.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyCodes;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyDownEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyDownHandler;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyPressEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyPressHandler;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyUpEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyUpHandler;
import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.NumberFormat;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextArea;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextBox;

/**
 * Entry point classes define <code>onModuleLoad()</code>.
 */
public class GwtTest implements EntryPoint {

    private TextArea messages;

    /**
     * This is the entry point method.
     */
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        // Add the textbox to receive events and a place to write messages
        final TextBox nameField = new TextBox();
        nameField.setText("");

        messages = new TextArea();
        messages.setText("");

        RootPanel.get().add(nameField);
        RootPanel.get().add(messages);
        messages.setSize("75%", "400px");

        // Focus the cursor on the name field when the app loads
        nameField.setFocus(true);
        nameField.addKeyUpHandler(new KeyUpHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event) {
                printMessage("KeyUpEvent",
                             event.getNativeKeyCode(),
                             event.isAnyModifierKeyDown(),
                             event.isControlKeyDown());
            }
        });

        nameField.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyPressHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
                printMessage( "KeyPressEvent",
                              event.getCharCode(),
                              event.isAnyModifierKeyDown(),
                              event.isControlKeyDown());
            }
        });

        nameField.addKeyDownHandler(new KeyDownHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event) {
                printMessage( "KeyDownEvent", 
                              event.getNativeKeyCode(),
                              event.isAnyModifierKeyDown(),
                              event.isControlKeyDown() );
            }
        });
    }

    public void printMessage(String eventName, int code, boolean modifier, boolean control) {
        final NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getDecimalFormat();
        String message = eventName + " -  Char Code: " + formatter.format(code) + ".  ";

        if(code == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) {
            message += "Key is ENTER.  ";
        }

        if(modifier) 
            message += "Modifier is down.  ";

        if(control)
            message += "CTRL is down.  ";

        messages.setText(messages.getText() + "\n\n" + message );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    RichTextArea noteTextEditor = new RichTextArea();

    noteTextEditor.setVisible(true);

    noteTextEditor.addKeyDownHandler(new KeyDownHandler() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event) 
        {

            if( event.isControlKeyDown())
            {
                if(event.getNativeKeyCode() ==KeyCodes.KEY_SPACE)
                {
                    Window.alert("CTRL+SHIFT");
                }
            }
        }
    });
    RootPanel.get("gwtContainer").add(noteTextEditor);
```